# Flash CS6 | How set the default save under CS5 format?

Tags: flash, save, flash-cs5

**Flash CS6**

If the first save dialog choose *.fla(CS5), and next use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, it will still keep in CS6 format.

How to change that when press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> then "Flash Cs6" save to CS5?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change this default setting, unfortunately.
You'll just need to save in CS6 file format, and every time you really want it in CS5 format, just click "save as -> CS5 file type".

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Search here: _"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Adobe\Flash CS6\en_US\Configuration"_, but did not find anything similar.Can someone know if there is a setting in the files?